# How to get user's attributes from Identity in Blazor Server with organization authentication

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, blazor

In the template provided for authentication you see an email address displayed in the LoginDisplay component, which is what the `Name` property of `...Identity`, as shown below:

```xml
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
        <a href="AzureAD/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="AzureAD/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

What I would like to know is how to access other information about an authenticated user. Like a full name, for example, in a simple way. I've found that with `Linq` you can get data from the `Claims` property like so:

```
@context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "name").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString()
```

Is that how we should get that information, or is there a better/preferred way to access that data from an authenticated user?

Comment: the linq code `@context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "name").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString()` is very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have what is needed in `Claims` this is the best place to get it from. You could add extra claims to your `Identity` - see how to do that in [Adding extra claims in ASP.NET Core web applications](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/add-extra-user-claims-in-asp-net-core-web-applications-1f28c98c9ec6). If it's not enough and you'd like to get full access to your `IdentityUser` entity inside your authorized component markup, you can do that via [`AuthenticationStateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authenticationstateprovider-service) and `UserManager<IdentityUser>` by injecting them to your `Blazor` page.

```
@page "/"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager;

<p>@Details</p>

@code {

    private string Details { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = await _UserManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Identity.Name)
            Details = $"Your user phone # is {user.PhoneNumber}.";
        }
        else
        {
            Details = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) `UserManager` and `SigninManager` aren't supported in Razor components.

Comment: You can retrieve user via DB Context from Users DbSet as well if you are using IdentityDbContext.

Comment: You have to define second user with diffrent name :
   var User = await ...